# IE 10 Returns JS Tag with JSON Response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, internet-explorer

I am running a username and password against an LDAP Active Directory and everything works fine in Chrome, but not in IE

My loginform.php submits GET data to login.php and then recieves a JSON encoded response (or at least it's supposed to)

The issue is that the response it receives includes a random JS tag that is not present anywhere in the code...

**loginform.php - enclosed in JS tags**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loginpanel form .btn').click(function() {
        var formdatau = $('#loginpanel form').find('input[name="username"]').val();
        var formdatap = $('#loginpanel form').find('input[name="password"]').val();

        $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-info').text('Loading');

        $.getJSON('login.php', { username: formdatau, password: formdatap }, function(obj) {
            if(obj.response == 'success') {
                document.cookie="auth="+obj.user;
                $('#loginpanel form .btn').removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-success').text('Success');
                location.href='index.php';
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**login.php - recieves the username and password then runs against LDAP and encodes JSON response**

```
<?php
include('functions.php');

$_GET['username'] = strtoupper($_GET['username']);

$ldap_columns = NULL;
$ldap_connection = NULL;
$ldap_password = 'testpassword';
$ldap_username = 'CN=dom-service-mgr-svc,OU=Service Accounts,OU=Special Users,DC=HCHC';


    $ldap_connection = ldap_connect($set['ldaphost']);

if (FALSE === $ldap_connection){
}

ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0); 

if (TRUE !== ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $ldap_username, $ldap_password)){
}


$ldap_base_dn = 'DC=hchc';
$search_filter = "(&(name=".$_GET['username']."))";
$result = ldap_search($ldap_connection, $ldap_base_dn, $search_filter, array('distinguishedname'));
if (FALSE !== $result){
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);
    if ($entries['count'] > 0){
        $userdn = $entries[0]['distinguishedname'][0];
        $pass = $_GET['password'];
    }
}


$dobind = ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $userdn, $pass);
if($dobind) {
    $resp = 'success';
} else {
    $resp = 'failure';
}

$resp = array('response'=>$resp,'user'=>$_GET['username']);
echo json_encode($resp);
?>
```

I do get a success response so the LDAP authentication is working and the response is formatted into JSON

```
<script type="javascript">

</script>
{"response":"success","user":"42033"}
```

Above is what gets responded to IE10

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you saying you don't know where the `<script type="javascript"></script>` comes from when viewing with ie10?  What's inside functions.php?

Comment: browser doesn't just make data up and insert it into the response.

Comment: I've literally searched every file in the directory for that tag in np++ and no dice, so apparently it does.. Idk, I'm not an IE guy.